TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (Getting data from firebase)
having some trouble while displaying data in my NextJS app.
I'm fetching data from Firebase, the interface looks like so:
export default interface IUser {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  uid: string;
  profileImageURL: string;
  publicData: {
    phone: string;
    address: string;
  }
}


When i'm accessing users/[id]/page.tsx i'm fetching the data:

const [userData, setUserData] = useState({} as IUser);

    useEffect(() => {

      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          setIsLoading(true);
          const IUser = await fetchUserData(params.id)
          .then((data) => {
            setUserData(data)
            setIsLoading(false);
          })
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
      };
    
      fetchData();
    }, []);

When i try to display the data anything that is not in publicData is displayed without a problem, that being name, email, etc. When i try to access and display userData.publicData.address, i get an error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')
Not really sure what is the issue here, since console logs do show the data without a problem, thought it maybe related to the User interface.
Thanks in advance for all the tips and solutions.
UPDATE
Adding a screenshot of the firebase structure

Also adding code of fetchUserData
import IUser from "../interfaces/User";
import { getCache, setCache } from "./cache";

export const fetchUserData = async (uid: string): Promise<IUser> => {

    const cacheKey = 'userData_' + uid;
    const cachedData = getCache(cacheKey);

  if (cachedData) {
    console.log('Returning cached data:', cachedData);
    return cachedData as IUser;
  }

    const response = await fetch('https://dev/auth/user?id=' + uid,
        {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch user data");
    }
const data: IUser = await response.json();
console.log('Fetched data:', data);
setCache(cacheKey, data);

return data;
};


There's not enough information in the question to know what the problem is.  1) You haven't shown the code of fetchUserData, so we don't know how you are querying the database.  2) We can't see the contents of the database, so we don't know if your interface and queried data actually match (it sounds like they don't).  Please edit the question to show a complete minimal reproducible example that anyone can use to duplicate the unexpected results.  We should be able to copy what you show and observe the same.

@DougStevenson apologies, my bad. I have added the screenshot and code of fetchUserData. The api returns a json of userData

Since we can't run that backend code and generate a meaningful response, you should at least show the exact JSON it returns so we can see what your app is trying to work with.  Again, we should be able to duplicate the behavior of your code using the information you provide.  I will also point out that you are likely not showing the line of code that causes the error accessing address.

The json being returned:
{
"uid": "oBcb8YrV0iOvajd6XEe686WBb4s2",
"name": "Name Surname",
"profileImageURL": "https://ca.slack-edge.com",
"email": "email@email.com",
"publicData": {
"phone": "123456",
"address": "Addressas"
}
}

All of the relevant information should be in the quesiton itself (not buried in comments).  Especially the line of code that causes the crash.

This is happening because where ever you are trying to use display data or use data. You haven't checked weather data is available or not. fetching data takes some time. so you must add condition where before using the data, you should check weather data is fetched or not. For example: In react when rendering you can do
   userData?.length > 0 && userData?.map(user => {
           //what ever data you are trying to render
});

And not forget to use '?' before dot or otherwise you will see error screen. At least your app won't crash.
Hope that will help you.
Thanks

Makes sense, thanks! I do wonder why any data that is not in publicData is accessible straight away, i get the error only when trying to access publicData Object.
